# Imageloader Several Images To ViewPager

Tags: java, android-viewpager, imageview, android-volley, imageloader

The following is part of code that retrieves images from a DB to a viewpager using volley. How can i have the seven pictures loaded to the imageview (**LOAD ALL IMAGES** location).
If i type any picture at LOAD ALL IMAGES location  independently e.g picture2 or picture3 it is loading correctly.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

  ////////

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
        SliderUtils utils = sliderImg.get(position);

        String picture = utils.getSliderImageUrl();
        String picture2 = utils.getSliderImage2Url();
        String picture3 = utils.getSliderImage3Url();
        String picture4 = utils.getSliderImage4Url();
        String picture5 = utils.getSliderImage5Url();
        String picture6 = utils.getSliderImage6Url();
        String picture7 = utils.getSliderImage7Url();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(**LOAD ALL IMAGES**,ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView, 
        R.drawable.placeholder, R.drawable.error));
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
        /////
            }
        });
        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        vp.addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        View view = (View) object;
        vp.removeView(view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NyP Just add a string array of your pictures and set it in your imageview as follows. Below the picture vars

`String [] urls = new String[] {picture, picture2, ........}`

Then load in image loader `imageLoader.get(urls,ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView, 
        R.drawable.placeholder, R.drawable.error));`

Comment: Thank yoy @shinsky paul it works with afew modifications using picasso